# Is it possible in LR 5 to add unique metadata titles to a large amount of images?

Tags: lightroom, metadata

So I use squarespace for my website.  Clients can come and see their images to choose which ones they want.  In order for them to know which ones to pick, I have to tag titles on the images for them to show.  Is there a way to add titles to the images in bulk, but add unique titles instead of one title for the whole batch of photos?
Does that make sense?  I don't want to go in each and every photo to add a new title if I don't have to.

Comment: Are you thinking something like: "title1", "title2", etc? or something different?

Comment: If you only need a unique identifier, is there a reason file name doesn't work?  I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish that would be beyond simply using a filename.

Answer (score 1):

**I think your problem is as follows.**

You have lots of pictures in your lightroom catalog, but they don't have a unique title. They might have an empty title field, or a nonunique, generic title such as "Birds" (in 100s of pictures)

You (or your webapp that is linked to your lightroom catalog) want unique titles, for example, instead of "Birds" you want BIrds123, Birds124, ... Birds878

**The (INCOMPLETE) strategy to update titles this way is:**

Read this blog post by master programmer James O'Neill,
http://jamesone111.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/getting-to-the-data-in-adobe-lightroomwith-or-without-powershell/

[Download](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) the required ODBC Driver for sqlite Databases, which will enable powershell to access the lightroom catalog, which is of the file type "sqlite database". (Consider it an Excel .xlsx file, which are really just .zip files. Try it. Open a .xlsx File with a .zip Editor. Same with lightroom catalog, its Extension .lrcat corresponds to .sqlite )

Install The free ODBC Driver.

Download James O'Neills Code (a zip file)
https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=1efe2682bfbbd817&id=1EFE2682BFBBD817!2894
This is a Powershell Script.
Inspect the code.

Try to Run it,

or copy the sql out from it and run it in a command line client such as 
[sqlite manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) (a firefox add-on)

This does read-only access to the database.
Executes SQL select statements.

Write a new function which includes an SQL UPATE  statement that updates the title field according to your needs.

PSEUDOCODE:

```
UPDATE some_table set title = title + "_" + AgLibraryFile.id_local
```

*Sorry I cannot be more specific at this time. But you weren't in your question either*.

Maybe there is a better way. This is a low-level access method.